# Angularjs can't show object in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i can't show object data in my html, just get blank field. I can see data with Angularjs Batarang, but just can't show it in html. Thank you for any answer.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Idle">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="IdleCtrl">
    <pre>{{ myData.length }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ myData | json}}</pre>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.11.2 used here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/myapp/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myapp/filters.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Idle', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('IdleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Custom-Header"] = "Angular";

    $http.get('data/currentUser').then(function(request) {
        $scope.myData = request.data;
    });
}]);
```

**data/currentUser json**

```
{"login":1,"hours":10,"steamInfo":{"provider":"steam","_json":{"steamid":"76561198015496944","communityvisibilitystate":3,"profilestate":1,"personaname":"SLI","lastlogoff":1444503135,"commentpermission":1,"profileurl":"http://steamcommunity.com/id/slipros/","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258.jpg","avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258_medium.jpg","avatarfull":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258_full.jpg","personastate":1,"realname":"Kirill Malikov","primaryclanid":"103582791435895197","timecreated":1257803858,"personastateflags":0,"gameid":"730","loccountrycode":"RU","locstatecode":"66","loccityid":42316},"id":"76561198015496944","displayName":"SLI","photos":[{"value":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258.jpg"},{"value":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258_medium.jpg"},{"value":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/4d/4d66e9aa26d7d797e391509f964a06402f884258_full.jpg"}],"identifier":"http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561198015496944"}}
```

**image preview**
[image: That what i get]

Comment: Are you using angular with another framework like laravel?

Comment: I use it with nodejs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that whatever framework you might be using Angular with, is interfering with the way you *echo* your data using `{{` and `}}`.

Try changing the aforementioned to the following:

```
<pre>@{{ myData.length }}</pre>
<pre>@{{ myData | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you man. You are totaly right. I just turn off swig render engine that use curly quotes and now all work's fine. Thank you.